# C++ How am I able to access this strings s.size index?

Tags: c++

```
void run_case() {
    int N, K;
    cin >> N >> K;
    string S;
    cin >> S;
    cout << S[6] << '\n';
    int goodness = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N/2-1; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ' ' << S[i] << ' ' << N - i << ' ' << S[N-i] << '\n';
        if (S[i] != S[N - i]) goodness++;
    }
    cout << goodness << '\n';
}
```

So I entered this input:

> 1
>
> 6 1
>
> CABABC

S's size is 6 why am I able to print it out and do all this stuff when S[6] doesn't exist..? S[5] is the last char can anyone explain why this is happening? I mean I know that C style strings have an extra char to signal that it's over but what's going on here?

Comment: `S[6]` does exist. Its the null terminator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: If I enter "Help" to your prompt, then S[6] is out of bounds.  Think about that one.

Comment: If you really entered what your input says, including the space between `6` and `1` on the second line, then `CABABC` is irrelevant; the string `S` contains `"1"` .

Comment: Oops yeah my bad I have one more line of input in main but from what someone else said I guess C++ strings are null terminated just like C strings

Comment: Regardless of the validity of `S[6]` in your particular example, C++, in general, doesn't check whether array or string index values are in bounds.  It's up to you to get it right.  I say in general, because, IIRC, MSVC Debug builds _do_ check.

Comment: If you want better bounds checking (at a small performance penalty, of course), use `S.at(6)` instead.

Comment: @tommyk no, `std::string` is not null terminated. You can place a `\0` in the middle of a `std::string` without affecting its size. Though any function that expects a null terminated string won't like that. The behavior of `S[ S.size()]` is to allow easier use of such functions when needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not sure I would express it quite like that.  It _is_ nul terminated (in the sense that there's a nul at the end) but there might also be a nul in the middle.  But only if you put one there, and that's unusual.

Comment: As stated above,  `S[6]` is valid, but otherwise welcome to the wacky world of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (UB). With UB, C++ leaves exactly what will happen up to the writers of the compiler and library.  This allows them to optimize for speed by assuming you know what you are doing and won't screw up, slow things down by adding extra checking in case you screw up, or anything else they want to do. Generally optimizing for speed is what's chosen and the typical result accessing out of bounds with the CPU deciding what to do.

Comment: @PaulSanders afaik `std::string` does not need the terminator and it is just due to compatibility with c-strings. I don't know how to express it in a good way. I just think it is important to be aware that the position of the first `\0` is not what determines the size of a `std::string`. I had to learn the lesson the hard way when I deserialized some protobuff and got only a fraction of the message because of that wrong assumption

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sure, it doesn't _need_ it, but it does guarantee it.  As for your painful memory, I guess the moral of the story there is "don't put embedded nul's in `std::string`s, it will come back to bite you".  If you want to store binary data, use `std::vector` to avoid nasty surprises later.

Comment: @PaulSanders it wasnt me who put it ;).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::operator[ s.size() ]` has changed in C++11. [Before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

> 1. If `pos == size()`, the behavior is undefined.
> 2. If `pos == size()`, a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned.

Where 1) refers to the non-const overload and 2) to the const overload. Since C++11:

> If `pos == size()`, a reference to the character with value `CharT()` (the null character) is returned.
> For the first (non-const) version, the behavior is undefined if this character is modified to any value other than `CharT()`.

When the size of the string is `6` then `S[6]` is completely fine. You just are not allowed to assign anything to it other than `\0`.

---

However, as mentioned in a comment, when your first input is `1` then `S == "1"` and accessing any index other than `0` or `1` is out-of-bounds. Attempting to access an out-of-bounds index is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. In the worst case the code might appear to work fine. It is important to understand that undefined behavior is typically not caught by compiler errors (though often compilers can warn about it).